# Proving similarity in a rectangle

Tags: trigonometry

IN the rectangle ABCDM AB= 2X AD, M is the midpoint of AD, and BM intersects AC at P.
APM is similar to CPB
3CP=2CA

Prove that 9 x  CP^2  = 5 x AB^2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The similarity of $APM$ and $CPM$ comes from the fact that the corresponding angles are all the same. Since $BC=2AM$, you must also have that $CP=2AP$ and so $CA=CP+AP=3AP$ so that $2CA=3CP$. Now, Considering the triangle $ABC$, we see that $AB^2+BC^2=CA^2$. But $BC^2=4AB^2$ and so $5AB^2=CA^2=\frac{9}{4} CP^2$.